# WPF MouseEnter/MouseLeave/MouseMove Event Tunneling

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a button where the contents change when the mouse enters the button.
Currently, this is the code that I'm working with:

### Xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="One" 
                Content="ONE" 
                Height="50" 
                Width="Auto" 
                MouseEnter="One_OnMouseEnter" 
                MouseLeave="One_OnMouseLeave" />
        <Button x:Name="Two" 
                PreviewMouseMove="Two_OnMouseEnter">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Black" 
                         Height="40" 
                         Width="40" />
                <Label Content="TWO" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

### C# Code-Behind File

```
private void One_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
        b.Foreground = Brushes.Purple;
        b.FontSize = 24;
    }
}

private void One_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
        b.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        b.FontSize = 12;
    }
}

private void Two_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    Ellipse el = sender as Ellipse;
    if (el != null)
    {
        el.Height = 60;
        el.Width = 60;
        el.Fill = Brushes.White;
    }

    Label l = sender as Label;
    if (l != null)
    {
        l.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }

    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    if (g != null)
    {
        g.Height = 200;
        g.Width = 200;
    }
}
```

The first button that's there works as expected.
When the mouse moves onto the "One" button, the text contents changes as expected. Text color changes to purple, and font size increases.

[image: Normal]

[image: Mouse Over]

I am trying to do something similar with the second button. Increase the size and change the color of the elliptical, change the color of the label, and change the size of the grid.

The problem is that the second button does not seem to respond as expected. I've tried to use `PreviewMouseMove`, which I understand to use a Tunneling routing strategy, which should trigger on the Button's child elements. I have used breakpoints to check, and the event seems to only trigger with the sender being the Button.

My question is: Why isn't the event being raised on the children as I've read that the Tunneling routing strategy is supposed to work and what can I do to fix it?

Also, the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events seem to follow the Bubbling routing strategy, but the behavior more closely resembles what I want to do. Can I force this to use a Tunneling routing strategy?

---

### edit:

In order to further explain the goal of this project:

What I am intending to do, is to have a more complete understanding of Event Tunneling in WPF.

This morning, I examined the book more and found a way to make this work when the mouse enters the area of each specific child, which is an improvement.

Here is the new code within the C# Code-Behind File:

```
private void Two_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse el = e.OriginalSource as Ellipse;
    if (el != null)
    {
        el.Height = 60;
        el.Width = 60;
        el.Fill = Brushes.Orange;
    }
    TextBlock t = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
    if (t != null)
    {
        t.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
    }
    Grid g = e.OriginalSource as Grid;
    if (g != null)
    {
        g.Height = 200;
        g.Width = 200;
    }
}
```

The difference with this code is that it uses the `MouseEventArgs e` object within the method signature, casting `e.OriginalSource` as the object type instead of casting the `sender` object.

In addition, this code is called using the `PreviewMouseMove` Event call in the XAML file:

```
<Button x:Name="Two" PreviewMouseMove="Two_OnMouseEnter">
```

which appears to only allow the contents to change when the mouse enters the area, but not when the mouse leaves the area. Which leads me back to part of my original question: can I force `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` to follow the Tunneling Routing Strategy?

Comment: my suggestion is to use styles triggers in separate file - resource dictionary or whatever

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish with this project is to gain a fundamental understanding of Event Tunneling in WPF. Even though styles triggers might produce the desired results for the program, in this particular situation, I want to stick with attempting to use event tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing anything because the event is coming from the `Button` (which is therefore the `sender`).

Something like this would be what you are trying to do:

```
private void Two_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    Grid g = b.Content as Grid;
    Ellipse el = g.Children[0] as Ellipse;
    Label l = g.Children[1] as Label;

    g.Height = 200;
    g.Width = 200;

    el.Height = 60;
    el.Width = 60;
    el.Fill = Brushes.White;

    l.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To explain the tunneling strategy a bit more, consider the following example (I've removed the event handlers for "One" for convenience):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="One" Content="ONE" Height="50" Width="Auto" />
        <Button x:Name="Two">
            <Grid PreviewMouseMove="Grid_PreviewMouseMove">
                <Ellipse Fill="Black" Height="40" Width="40" PreviewMouseMove="Ellipse_PreviewMouseMove" />
                <Label Content="TWO" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       PreviewMouseMove="Label_PreviewMouseMove"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = sender as Grid;

    if (g != null)
    {
        g.Height = 200;
        g.Width = 200;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sender: " + sender.GetType() + "; Source: " + e.Source.GetType());
}

private void Ellipse_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse el = sender as Ellipse;

    if (el != null)
    {
        el.Height = 60;
        el.Width = 60;
        el.Fill = Brushes.White;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sender: " + sender.GetType() + "; Source: " + e.Source.GetType());
}

private void Label_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label l = sender as Label;

    if (l != null)
    {
        l.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sender: " + sender.GetType() + "; Source: " + e.Source.GetType());
}
```

These methods could theoretically be refactored into one method, with some logic applied to detect the `Type` of the `sender`, but it would still be in the XAML three times.

One thing to notice is that the `Grid` won't fire its own events unless you set it's `Background` property (e.g., to `Transparent`), though it will still fire when the `Ellipse` and `Label` fire.

Another thing to notice is that when the `Label` fires the event, i.e. when you move the mouse over the `Label`, the event handler for the `Ellipse` is not called. This is because the tunneling strategy proceeds logically down the tree, rather than visually. If you look at the "Source: " part in the message in the Output window you'll see what I mean. The same would also be true for bubbling events.

As a general observation, the thing with this kind of strategy is that with events firing from different elements, your control isn't really functioning as one single `Button`, which looks to be the intention. If you move the mouse in slowly, you'll notice the `Ellipse` fires first, then the `Label` once you reach that.

There aren't any `PreviewMouseEnter` or `PreviewMouseLeave` events, so tunneling couldn't be used for that anyway.

Comment: This doesn't explain the Tunneling routing strategy. According to the definition of the Tunneling routing strategy: "The event is first raised on the root, then on each element down the tree until the source element has been reached (or until a handler halts the tunneling by marking the event as handled)." With the *source* being "the element in the logical tree that originally raised the event."

Comment: This procedure also appears to only work on a very specific logical tree, which is apparently counter to the way that WPF is meant to be used.

Comment: The tunneling strategy means that if you move the mouse over the `Ellipse`, the event will be fired (or an attempt would be made) on the `Button` first, then the `Grid`, etc., but for that to happen you would need to define event handlers on each element.

Comment: So you’re telling me that the event handler method should fire with the ellipse as the sender when the mouse pointer enters the space that the ellipse inhabits? If that’s what you mean, this is not what I observe with the current code.

Comment: Well, it depends what you want to do, I was just mirroring what it looked like you were trying to do. Personally, I'd take @GlacialMan's advice and look into triggers, if all you're wanting to do is change the appearance of the `Button` when the mouse is over it?

Comment: [new comment with more information about the project intention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104033/wpf-mouseenter-mouseleave-mousemove-event-tunneling/48104705?noredirect=1#comment83207563_48104033)